# Bash command as variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to store the start of a sed command inside a variable like this:

```
sedcmd="sed -i '' "
```

Later I then execute a command like so:

```
   $sedcmd s/$orig_pkg/$package_name/g $f
```

And it doesn't work. Running the script with bash -x, I can see that it is being expanded like:

```
   sed -i ''\'''\'''
```

What is the correct way to express this?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a shell function:

```
mysed () {
    sed -i "" "$@"
}
```

and call it like this:

```
$ mysed s/$orig_pkg/$package_name/g $f
```

Comment: I missed that @larsman suggest this at the end of his answer.

Answer (score 2):

It works when the command is only one word long:

```
$ LS=ls
$ $LS
```

But in your case, the shell is trying the execute the *program* `sed -i ''`, which does not exist.

The workaround is to use `$SHELL -c`:

```
$ $SHELL -c "$LS"
total 0
```

(Instead of `$SHELL`, you could also say `bash`, but that's not entirely reliable when there are multiple Bash installations, the shell isn't actually Bash, etc.)

However, in most cases, I'd actually use a shell function:

```
sedcmd () {
    sed -i '' "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an alias or a function?  You can do alias as

```
alias sedcmd="sed -i '' "
```

Comment: Testing it like: #!/bin/bash

alias sedcmd="sed -i '' "
sedcmd
gives: ./test.sh: line 4: sedcmd: command not found

Comment: Aliases are not enabled by default in non-interactive shells, which is one reason to use a shell function instead. But you can turn on aliases using `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way for do that

```
alias sedcmd="sed -i ''"
```

Obviously remember that when you close your bash, this alias will be gone.
If you want to make it "permanent", you have to add it to your `.bashrc` home file (if you want to make this only for a single user) or `.bashrc` global file, if you want to make it available for all users

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but my suggestion is:

```
sedcmd="sed -i "
$sedcmd s/$orig_pkg/$package_name/g $f
```

You must set variables `orig_pkg` `package_name` and `f` in your shell first.

If you're replacing variable names in a file, try:

```
$sedcmd s/\$orig_pkg/\$package_name/g $f
```

Still `f` must be set to the file name you're working on.